# redirect .html to non html pages wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I had old html website which had .html pages and i want to redirect to non .html pages which wordpress has.

for eg.

Old site
http://myweb212.com/About-Us/jony-test.html

wordpress site.

http://myweb212.com/About-Us/jony-test

There are many pages in website so is this possible do this with one rule?

I tried using a rule but it breaks some of the images of upload folder and shows 404.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the new rule between another rule (`RewriteRule`) and its associated conditions (`RewriteCond`) breaks this other rule.

So when you move the rule to the beginning or to the end, it should work as is.

One minor nitpick, *never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)! When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)).